# Widgets.js file erroring out when I try to extend a file

Tags: javascript, aem

I'm trying to develop a custom xtype that extends the tags xtype defined in

```
/libs/cq/tagging/widgets/source/widgets/TagInputField.js
```

I have the function defined in another file

```
CQ.tagging.customTagInputField = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.TagInputField, { /*A whole bunch of code here */ });

CQ.Ext.reg("customtags", CQ.tagging.customTagInputField);
```

Yet every time I try to boot up a page containing my custom widget I get an error in my console saying

```
TypeError: sp is undefined

spp = sp.prototype;
```

According to the all wise and knowing Google. This kind of error usually means I'm trying to extend something that doesn't exist. However changing

```
CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.TagInputField,
```

to something a bit more specific like

```
CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.tagging.TagInputField,
```

Produces and error saying CQ.tagging is undefined. Is there a way for me to extend this file in CQ5? If so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `/libs/cq/tagging/widgets/source/widgets/TagInputField.js`, you'll see that the tags widget is declared as `CQ.tagging.TagInputField`, so I believe your second approach of extending that field is correct.

You mentioned that your custom xtype is in a separate file - when your page loads and your extension code is invoked, has the tagging widgets library loaded?  You may need to add the tagging category to your custom client lib as a dependency.

On custom JS clientlibs and dependencies:
http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/HowToCreateCustomClientLib.html